# Change extension of specific filetype on current folder and subdirectories with .bat

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I would like to rename all the .log as .ok from a particular folder and subdirectories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will usually work just fine:

```
@echo off
for /r "PathToYourFolderHere" %%F in (.) do ren "%%F\*.log" *.ok
```

But the above can have problems if short file names are enabled on your drive and you have extensions longer than 3 characters. It will also rename files like `name.log2` because the short name will have an extension of `.log`.

The following will only rename true `.log` files:

```
@echo off
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in (
  '"dir /b /s /a-d PathToYourFolder\*.log|findstr /lie .log"'
) do ren "%%F" *.ok
```

**Note:** The rules for how RENAME treats wildcards can be found at [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090)

Answer (score 1):

run a .bat file from the folder containing:

```
for /R %%x in (*.log) do rename "%%x" "%%~nx.ok"
```

- /R for recursive
- %%~nx for the filename without extension

Comment: +1, This will work in most cases. But it will also rename files like `name.logX` if short file names are enabled. It will always work if short names are disabled, or if no extensions longer than 3 chars exist that begin with `.log`.